# Android add layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a view which contains a LinearLayout defined by an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/main"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:paddingTop="5dip"
  android:paddingBottom="5dip"
  android:background="#CCC">

     <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/hours"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

which just adds a bar on the left side of the screen.
Now depending on the input of the user I would like to add dynimally linearlayouts next to the bar.

The code to display the bar is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private static int HOURS_PER_DAY = 24;
Context context = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.list);

    setListAdapter(new ListAdapter() {

        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean isEnabled(int arg0) {
            return false;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return HOURS_PER_DAY;
        }

        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return 0;
        }

        public int getItemViewType(int arg0) {
            return 0;
        }


        public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View listItem = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list,getListView(),false);



             return listItem;
        }

        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return false;
        }

        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0) {
        }

        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0) {
        }

    });
```

And in the java code I would like to add new linearlayouts next to the defined one in the xml file

Comment: If you implement a `ListActivity` with a custom layout, then (from the documentation) "your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list""

Comment: So what would I have to change just an id for 'View listItem...'?